# Disable button base on the json value

Tags: json, angularjs

so I have a json object and also a edit button. I am wondering how to disable that edit button if the value is not equal to Peter so that the user cannot edit it.

```
angular.module('app')

.factory('WebApi', function () {

//Dummy Data
var name = [{
        value: "Peter",
        text: "Peter"
    }, {
        value: "John",
        text: "John"
    }, {
        value: "Lucy",
        text: "Lucy",
    }, {
        value: "Hawk",
        text: "Hawk"
    }];

var tempData = [];

//Display 100 item 
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    var selectedName = name[Math.floor((Math.random() * name.length))];

   tempData.push({
     name: selectedName.text


    })
};
```

constants.js

```
angular.module('app')

.factory('Constants', function () {

    return {
        status: {
            Peter: 'Peter'
        }
    };

});
```

button

```
 <ion-list can-swipe="listCanSwipe">
                            <ion-item ng-repeat="data in tempData"
                                      item="data">
                              Name: {{data.name}}

                                <ion-option-button class="button-calm"
                                                   ng-click="edit(data)">
                                    Edit
                                </ion-option-button>

                            </ion-item>

                        </ion-list>
```

Comment: You need to add more details. Like what is data in your view? Additionally, how are you handling array names?

Comment: Hi nikhil, I have the    var tempData = []; as my array, and I use the word "data" to display the item in my list view.
It is  ng-repeat = "data in tempData".
 <ion-item ng-repeat="data in tempData"
                                      item="data">
</ion-item>

Comment: Is name your tempData?

Comment: tempData is my array. name is my json object

Comment: Can you please add sample for the same. Additionally name as per the above snippet is an array.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the code above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83702/discussion-between-anonymous-and-nikhil).

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-disabled:
Examlpe:-

```
<ion-option-button ng-disabled="name.value!='peter'" class="button-calm"ng-click="edit(data)">
      Edit
  </ion-option-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-disabled` like following

```
<ion-option-button ng-disabled="data.name!='peter'" class="button-calm"ng-click="edit(data)">
      Edit
  </ion-option-button>
```

For reference - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Answer (score 0):

In Html

```
 ng-disabled="someFunction()"
```

In your JS

```
$scope.someFunction = function() {

 // return true or false.

};
```